# Creating a GitHub Enterprise pull request from command line from master to other branches without using hub

Tags: github

I want to create a pull request for `qa`, trunks from `master`.
This is possible using the GitHub UI.

I am looking for a command line help to create pull request for the protected branches without using `hub`.

Comment: Why can't you use `hub`?

Comment: @ScottWeldon We want to trigger pull-requests to all trunks, qa when our devs push their code to master branch. So we want to enable it via Github hooks without using another tool. Can you suggest a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pull requests are not something Git supports. It is a GitHub specific thing. A pull requests generally can be anything, from an email saying "here, merge this commit from that repository on my local machine please", over patches sent via some matter, to some formal technically supported thing like GitHub does.

So to use GitHub pull requests from the command line, you **must** use some commandline tool like `git-spindle` (or `hub` if you prefer it) that is able to speak to the GitHub API to do the GitHub specific stuff. You can of course also use some generic HTTP tool like `curl` or `wget` or `HTTPie` to speak to the GitHub API.

Comment: Hi @Vampire Thanks for the information. I am not looking for any tool but want to know if there is any commands to create the pull request. I don't want to use tools just for a functionality which seems to me as an overkill. Additionally the tool specific is specific to github.com and not a enterprise inhouse instance. Does it configure the host url ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I adjusted my answer accordingly

Comment: `git-spindle` can talk to GitHub cloud, own GitHub Enterprise server, GitLab cloud, own GitLab server and BitBucket cloud currently.

Comment: I would be more interested to know if we can put a hook on push to master branch using a webhook and fire the git pullrequest creation api for protected branches. Will that be a valid concept if I look to automate the process?

Comment: I think so, yes. Nothing prevents you to call the API to create a pull request from a post-receive hook, or from a called web hook.